# AWS SignatureDoesNotMatch error on ap-south-1 region

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, evaporate.js

I have created pre-signed URL for post file to AWS s3 bucket, it's working for ap-southeast-1 but for ap-south-1 it shown me signature does not match error.

I'm using sign v4 and evaporate.js to do multipart upload
[image]

Answer (score 0):

AWS Pre-Signed Urls are signed with SignatureV4 process which includes region in the [string](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-string-to-sign.html) to sign.

> 20150830/us-east-1/{service}/aws4_request

One region Url will not work with another region.